# My code's body takes up extra space from the top despite giving it proper CSS margin values. Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Tags: html, css

The body of my code takes extra space from the top, the code written below shows that i have already assigned the body's margin as zero, but if you run it, the code will take about 20px from the top, can you please explain why is it happening.

I'm talking about this thing [in internet explorer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1qaylqpQE6INU1xSzdjQ3kxcXc/view?usp=sharing) and [in google chrome](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1qaylqpQE6IVUJ4ZkFqTTRCdDQ/view?usp=sharing):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gmail</title>
<style>
    body{
        margin:0;}
    .head{
        height:83px; margin:0; width:100%;}
    .logodiv{
        margin:0; padding:0 44px; width:auto; height:83px;}
    .logo{
        margin:20px auto 25px auto; height:auto; width:115px;}
    .body1{ 
        padding:0px 44px 100px; height:685px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="head">
        <div class="logodiv">
            <div class="logo">
                <img height="38px" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/logo_2x.png">   
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
<div class="body1">
    Hello
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct your top margin for logo `.logo{margin:0px auto 25px auto; height:auto; width:115px;}`
Go for further reading on css margin properties here [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Comment: Thank you Saubar, i appreciate your immediate help,
Also, Is there any way i can give the image a margin of 20px from the top ?

Comment: `img{margin-top:20px}`

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have default styles by default. Use a `CSS` reset these and standardize `CSS` behavior. Use: [Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [Normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

For this specific example, try using this CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

The body doesn't take extra space from the top. It shows that way because the logo is the first element to render in the DOM and has 20px top margin.
See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/g9r7crj7/1/) as it proves this point.

Comment: I copied the Meyer's code within the style tag, it style shows up the extra space, not only in chrome and explorer. But also in the live view option of Dreamweaver. i think it is some sort of inherited property, 

Can i try anything else ?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Yes Of course:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1qaylqpQE6IMFA1a2V0UmtTWE0/view?usp=sharing

I copied meyer's code in the style tag between:
/*This is the Meyer's code*/

Comment: Basically set `.logo { margin: 0 auto 25px; ... }` and you will get rid of that  20px margin on the top. `body` doesn't have any inherited extra top space.

Comment: I've done it, but it sticks my logo to the top
Is there anyway we can add a 20px extra space above the image, without getting that blank space ?

Comment: Click on the example link that I provided you. That's the solution!

Comment: This is my first day @ stackoverflow, and i'm already addicted,
Thank you for answering.
:)

Comment: Alright. Now please up vote my answer and mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: As soon as i have 15 reputation i will be able to vote up your answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the logo class as shown below

```
.logo{
    margin:0px auto 25px auto; height:auto; width:115px;}
```

Comment: Thank you, i've done it 
but is there a way we can still give the image a margin of 20 px from the top